# Python List Indexing Error

Tags: python, indexing, python-2.x

```
def getPrimeList(check):
    storedprimes = []
    i = 2
    while i <= check:
        if isPrime(check):
            storedprimes = storedprimes + [i]
        i = i + 1
    return storedprimes
def getPrimeFact(check):
    primelist = getPrimeList(check)
    prime_fact = []
    i = 0
    while check !=1:
        if check%primelist[i]==0:
            prime_fact=prime_fact+[primelist[i]]
            check = check/primelist[i]
        i = i + 1
        if i == len(primelist):
            i = 0
    return prime_fact
def getGCF(checks):
    a=0
    listofprimefacts=[]
    while a<len(checks):
        listofprimefacts=listofprimefacts+[getPrimeFact(checks[a])]
        a=a+1
    b=0
    storedprimes=[]
    while b<len(primefactlist):
        c=0
        while c<len(listofprimefacts[b]):
            if listofprimefacts[b][c] not in storedprimes:
                storedprimes=storedprimes+[listofprimefacts[b][c]]
            c=c+1
        b=b+1
    prime_exp=[]
    d=0
    while d<len(storedprimes):
        prime_exp=prime_exp+[0]
        d=d+1

    e=0
    while e<len(storedprimes):
        f=0
        while f<len(listofprimefacts):
            if f==0:
                prime_exp[e]=listofprimefacts[f].count(storedprimes[e])
            elif prime_exp[e]-(listofprimefacts[f].count(storedprimes[e]))>0:
                prime_exp[e]=listofprimefacts[f].count(storedprimes[e])                
            f=f+1
        e=e+1
    g=0
    GCF=1
    while g<len(primelist):
        GCF=GCF*(storedprime[g]**prime_exp[g])
        g=g+1
    return GCF
```

I am creating a program that will use these functions for the purpose of calculating fractions; however, after testing my GCF function in the shell I keep getting a list indexing error. I have no idea, where the error is coming from considering im 99% sure there is no problems with my indexes, usually i would not post such a "fixable" problem in SO but this time i just have no idea what the problem is, thanks again.

Oh and heres the exact error

```
File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    getGCF(checks)
  File "E:\CompProgramming\MidtermFuncts.py", line 31, in getGCF
    listofprimefacts=listofprimefacts+[getPrimeFact(checks[a])]
  File "E:\CompProgramming\MidtermFuncts.py", line 20, in getPrimeFact
    if check%primelist[i]==0:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Blender your name and sarcastic yet serious style of right makes me feel like ive met you before. Hello again stranger:D

Comment: Is this a learning exercise, or are you trying to solve a problem?  I'm pretty sure there are pre-existing Python solutions that should solve your fractions needs, but if you are learning then carry on.

Comment: Lets think of it as a learning experience :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mixed up `i` and `check` in your `getPrimeList()` function; you test if `check` is a prime, *not* `i`; here is the correct function:

```
def getPrimeList(check):
    storedprimes = []
    i = 2
    while i <= check:
        if isPrime(i):  # *not* `check`! 
            storedprimes = storedprimes + [i]
        i = i + 1
    return storedprimes
```

This, `primelist` will be set to an empty list (as `getPrimeList(check)` returns an empty list) and your `primelist[i]` (for *any* `i`) will fail with an index error.

Another way for `primelist` to be empty is when `isPrime()` never returns True; you don't show us that function to verify it.

Your next error is in `getGCF()`; you define a `listofprimefacts` variable (a list) first, but later refer to a non-existing `primefactlist` variable, leading to a `NameError`. The next name error is going to be `primelist` further in that function.

You really want to re-read the [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/); you are missing out on many python idioms in your code; specifically on how to create loops over sequences (hint: `for check in checks:` is easier to use than a `while` loop with an index variable) and how to append items to a list.

My personal toolkit defines this:

```
from math import sqrt

def prime_factors(num, start=2):
    """Return all prime factors (ordered) of num in a list"""
    candidates = xrange(start, int(sqrt(num)) + 1)
    factor = next((x for x in candidates if (num % x == 0)), None)
    return ([factor] + prime_factors(num / factor, factor) if factor else [num])
```

which doesn't need a `isPrime()` test.

Comment: The thing is im using python as a gateway to learning other langauges that is why the python convetional 'for' is not in any of my code, i am aware of what it is although i refrain myself from using it, also for testing purposes i open up the shell define checks ex:checks= 125,525,325 then i simply call getGCF(checks)

Comment: @Alvaro If you're deliberately ignoring language features, I'm not sure what you should expect. The `for` idiom is in loads of languages, either through some kind of iterator or it's spelt `foreach` or `for each` or some other syntantical construct - not sure you're doing yourself any good "learning" with this approach :)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to re-think how you attack this problem. In its current form, your code is really hard to work with.

Here's how I'd do it:

```
def is_prime(n):
    for i in range(2, int(n ** 0.5) + 1):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False

    return True

def prime_factors(number):
    factors = []

    for i in range(2, number / 2):
        if number % i == 0 and is_prime(i):
            factors.append(i)

    return factors

def gcf(numbers):
    common_factors = prime_factors(numbers[0])

    for number in numbers[1:]:
        new_factors = prime_factors(number)
        common_factors = [factor for factor in common_factors if factor in new_factors]

    return max(common_factors)
```

This line right here:

```
common_factors = [factor for factor in common_factors if factor in new_factors]
```

Is a list comprehension. You can unroll it into another `for` loop:

```
temp = []

for factor in common_factors:
    if factor in new_factors:
        temp.append(factor)

common_factors = list(temp)  # Pass by value, not by reference
```